# How to play a s3 video url in html video tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/***-***-videos/************.mp4". 
This is a s3  video url which I'm unable to play in html5 video tag or in other third party video players in my angular project.Is there any Mime type or configuration I need to do so as to play the video?Mime type I tried with is type = video/mp4.

Comment: What happens when you visit the url in the browser?

Comment: The video player shows a loading symbol,nothing more than that.Even I tried in a Cross origin issue disabled browser.

Comment: If you are using chrome, then when you visit the page, go to the network tab to monitor network activity. You might have to reload. Make sure your requests aren't blocked by the server ie make sure that the response status is not 404. Check the status first

Comment: Yes that's what,I tried in such a way that there won't be any issues like blocking the request's or not found

Comment: If that is the case, the browser should not have any problems playing the video. Have you tried it on any other browser?

Comment: yeah Abhishek.Did you ever faced this kind of problem?

Comment: Nope. But what i can suggest as an alternative is that if you have the video,upload it to some other domain

Comment: if you download the mp4 and run ffprobe against it you will be able to see how it's been encoded... browsers are pretty specific about their requirements so you may need to re-encode to match the specs

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this?

```html
<video width="100" height="100" controls>
  <source src="random.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="random.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: No @klaas weerstand.I achived it using a s3 stored public url.

Comment: `<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://xxxxx.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bear.mp4"
 type="video/mp4">
</video>`
Just to show how you can use your _s3 stored public url_ in a video tag and this works!